# Why are the URL's not displayed when I run the pdf?

Tags: compilation-error

I can't find the mistake here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
pointlessnumbers, 
%draft,
parskip=half,
automark
    ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\cdot}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{x}
\author{x}
\date{x}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\subsection{Quellen}
Abbildung $\ref{fig:7}$: $\url{de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelspaltexperiment}$, 13.3.22 13:29Uhr

Abbildung $\ref{fig:8}$: $\url{www.schule-bw.de/faecher-und-schularten/mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche-faecher/physik/unterrichtsmaterialien/wellen/interferenz/mehrfachspalte.html}$, 13.3.22 13:33Uhr

Abbildung $\ref{fig:8}$: $\url{www.google.com/search?q=dreifachspalt&sxsrf=APq-WBv9xT2QQ0FdNDcDKjurBfK31n_9mA:1647174717822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ7cD_i8P2AhVkSfEDHc4dCIoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=607&dpr=2$#:~:text=Schulentwicklung%20NRW,03%3A%$20Optisches%20Gitter}$

Abbildung $\ref{fig:10}$: Giancoli Physik, Pearson
Abbildung $\ref{fig:11}$: Giancoli Physik, Pearson
Abbildung $\ref{fig:13}$: $\url{de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beugung_(Physik)}[![enter image description here][1]][1]$, 16.3.22, 11:07 Uhr
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ... however there are much more errors than just using an obsolete package. Why on Earth do you warp your URLs in math mode?

Comment: also why is `\ref`  in math mode??

Comment: Using obsolete packages often come from use of not update tutorials found with search engines...

Comment: If this code is from a tutorial, please throw the tutorial away. The code is completely awful. It uses deprecated and obsolete packages, not needed options, not recommended code, inconvenient code, strange sequences of headings. To start with a more minimal but also cleaner code, see, e.g., [How to make a document template based on KOMA-Script](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_Template/) also available [in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_Template/).